# Issue when starting windows application in windows emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am trying to create a simple application with hello world in text box on button click in Microsoft visual studio 2010 Express for windows phone.

But when i try to debug it's showing "windows phone emulator has stopped working" and in console "connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments".

I am using windows 7 ultimate 32 bit.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5b659eea-9a4f-45ce-8418-b9097d586197/wp7x-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools#5b659eea-9a4f-45ce-8418-b9097d586197

Comment: ya i read already and i try all those mentioned steps but no effect. showing same errors.

Comment: Awkward question but...have you tried turning it off and on again? I mean your phone. I remember that I had the same problem and restart solved it. Or try again with another solution. Oh and I forgot to question that are you trying with a wp7 or a wp8 phone?

Comment: I am not using windows phone i just trying in Windows Emulator. I re-install and restart Visual studio and SDK many times but showing same problems. Thanks

Comment: Check for system logs or google a little to find the emulator logs path and check for errors